# Why Third-Cookies appear to me when i open a new windows in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, cookies

[image]

Hello, I have observed a problem in my cookie control. At first I thought everything worked fine because if I browse my website no third-party cookies appear, but when I open a new browser window cookies appear on my DevTools cookies agendas to my page as shown in the image, 1p_JAR, CONSET, NID, DEV.

I manage my personal statistics cookies manually that allow me to activate and deactivate the user but I don't know how to control that type of cookies.

I have also observed that this only happens in chrome in browsers such as Mozilla and Edge does not happen, only cookies that use my website appear.

I would like to know how I can control, block so that they do not leave or at least I can let the user decide whether or not to allow them

Comment: Think how Google make all their money :)

Comment: I understand, but I would like to know how I can control, block so that they do not leave or at least I can let the user decide whether or not to allow them

Comment: I ve other web site with the same politic of cookies implement and it not has that problem. Not appear anything if i open a new browser windows and i start to move for other pages.